# Mac Terminal SSH file transfer?

Tags: mac, ssh, terminal

Is there a way to transfer files directly from a Mac to another using only Terminal? Perhaps using SSH?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, you can use scp , which basically cp over ssh. It can work either way also, so:

```
scp ~/Document/Localfile remoteuser@remotemachine:~/Desktop
```

or

```
scp remoteuser@remotemachine:~/Destkop/remotefile ~/Desktop
```

The first command would copy a file to the remote machine, the second would copy a file from the remote to the local. The syntax is `<user>@<machine or ip>:<file>` you can do a `man scp` for more switches and options

Comment: No problem, please remember Gordon Davisson info below wrt Mac Metadata and the `-E` option

Comment: Remember to use `scp -r` to copy entire folders/dirs

Answer (score 4):

The `scp` command on Linux is how you do file transfers using SSH

Comment: scp works great on Macs with one caveat: if you want it to copy Mac-specific file metadata (resource forks, extended attributes, etc), be sure to use its `-E` option.

Answer (score 2):

Here is quick way of copying files using uuencode/uudecode and clipboard.

In terminal, while having connection opened on remote machine:

```
press CMD + K to clear the window
clear; uuencode filename < file
```

Then select and copy all text from the terminal window (CMD + A, CMD + C). Now open new terminal window, on your local system and do:

```
uudecode
```

Now press CMD + V now to paste uuencoded content of your file. Press CTRL + D after that to finish input to uudecode program. uudecode will create your file locally, under the name 'filename'.

Answer (score 1):

`scp` is the command you want. You need to have SSH logins enabled on the destination computer, and know the username and password for the destination computer.

```
scp file.txt user@destination-computer:/Users/user/Documents/file.txt
```